# First Activity is not Running in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-xml

I am new in Android, I am developing an app in android. I have developed a project with blank activity.

After that, I have created a User interface in layout folder and save as sign_up.xml.

After it, I have create a class file in src directory in which i have code as below:

```
import com.example.projectname.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class sign_Up_Activity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    }
}
```

And my `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like:

```
<activity android:name=".sign_Up_Activity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

[image]
Now I am running app but its crashed and getting error.

Could you please someone help me to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your error trace from logcat.

Comment: What's the error.You need to post your logcat trace to find out the problem.

Comment: Post also you layout xml..

Comment: In your logcat its shows ClasscastException for MainActivity. So can you tell me which one is your MainActivity??

Comment: Please post full android manifest file, something seems to be wrong there